# Facebook note shared info

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My client need to randomize over everyone that shared a specific note on his facebook page, it's like a raffle, however, i didn't found a way to get any info, even the name in a way that i can randomize over them, is there any way that i can fetch this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the [note for the comments or likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/) if you are looking at a specific note.  Or you can query the user for [all their notes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and loop over that.

Depending on what language you are using, randomly choosing from an array of items should be trivial.